# awk read from multi variables instead of files

Tags: bash, awk

I have two variables `$name` and `$birthday`

```
$> echo "$name"
Mack
Lee

$> echo "$birthday"
3rd 
May
```

I want to get output like this:

```
Mack  1 1
Lee  2 2
3rd  3 1
May 4 2
```

but,I enter the command:

```
$> echo -e "$name" "\n" "$birthday"|awk '{print $0,NR,FNR}'
```

And get this:

```
Mack  1 1
Lee  2 2
 3rd  3 3   ###here a space in the first
May 4 4
```

How can I remove the leading spaces and get expect FNR values？

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please be more clear in your question here? are you trying to push bash variables to `awk`? Please post sample of Input and sample of output too in your post.

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the quotes except the first and the last?

Comment: I just want read two variables into awk process like awk '{print $0,NR,FNR}' file1 file2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use process substitution:

```
$ awk '{print $0,NR,FNR}' <(echo -e "$name") <(echo -e "$birthday")
```

This should solve both problems, empty space and `FNR` values.
This basically passes two inputs into the `awk`, just like passing two input files.

Comment: Equivalent syntax not exactly right.FNR NOT correct.

Comment: The OP used `echo -e` apparently for the lone newline but you should probably simply use just `echo` or perhaps switch to `printf` for a properly portable alternative.

Comment: `FNR` will only be as expected if there are multiple input streams to Awk. Piping in the input will not work without significant refactoring.

Comment: @Michael - That's right! I've fooled myself. Removed.
@tripleee - +1 for `printf`

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can use a Bash process substitution. Each command in `<(cmd)` is exposed as a filehandle-like object to Awk and other processes.

```
awk '{print $0,NR,FNR}' <(echo "$name") <(echo "$birthday")
```

This really begs the question what you are *actually* hoping to accomplish, though. Having nontrivial amounts of data in shell variables is usually a symptom of a more fundamental design problem.

Comment: Maybe also look at answers for how to transpose columns and rows in Awk for a vaguely similar problem. Some clever labeling could allow you to `paste` arbitrarily large inputs and just add some finishing touches in Awk to get exactly the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "[Bash process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50792809/16168468)" worked for me. Many thanks.
I'm using variables instead of files as I now no longer need to clean up workspace files under /tmp that I was using before. Also am using 2 data inputs to "awk" to join 2 tables of data. "awk" arrays have a dynamic index method, where it does not always have to be [0] for the 1st element, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50792809/16168468) for the 2nd etc. You can use individual values like a key field in a database table.